# python script to draw the chart of the selected stocks

Tags: python

I have a code like this

```
public class PythonRunner
{
/// <summary>
/// Instantiates a new <see cref="PythonRunner" /> instance.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="interpreter">
/// Full path to the Python interpreter ('python.exe').
/// </param>
/// <param name="timeout">
/// The script timeout in msec. Defaults to 10000 (10 sec).
/// </param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
/// Argument <paramref name="interpreter" /> is null.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="FileNotFoundException">
/// Argument <paramref name="interpreter" /> is an invalid path.
/// </exception>
/// <seealso cref="Interpreter" />
/// <seealso cref="Timeout" />
public PythonRunner(string interpreter, int timeout = 10000) { ... }

/// <summary>
/// Occurs when a python process is started.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="PyRunnerStartedEventArgs" />
public event EventHandler<PyRunnerStartedEventArgs> Started;

/// <summary>
/// Occurs when a python process has exited.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="PyRunnerExitedEventArgs" />
public event EventHandler<PyRunnerExitedEventArgs> Exited;

/// <summary>
/// The Python interpreter ('python.exe') that is used by this instance.
/// </summary>
public string Interpreter { get; }

/// <summary>
/// The timeout for the underlying <see cref="Process" /> component in msec.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// See <see cref="Process.WaitForExit(int)" /> for details about this value.
/// </remarks>
public int Timeout { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Executes a Python script and returns the text that it prints to the console.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="script">Full path to the script to execute.</param>
/// <param name="arguments">Arguments that were passed to the script.</param>
/// <returns>The text output of the script.</returns>
/// <exception cref="PythonRunnerException">
/// Thrown if error text was outputted by the script (this normally happens
/// if an exception was raised by the script). <br />
/// -- or -- <br />
/// An unexpected error happened during script execution. In this case, the
/// <see cref="Exception.InnerException" /> property contains the original
/// <see cref="Exception" />.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
/// Argument <paramref name="script" /> is null.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="FileNotFoundException">
/// Argument <paramref name="script" /> is an invalid path.
/// </exception>
/// <remarks>
/// Output to the error stream can also come from warnings, that are frequently
/// outputted by various python package components. These warnings would result
/// in an exception, therefore they must be switched off within the script by
/// including the following statement: <c>warnings.simplefilter("ignore")</c>.
/// </remarks>
public string Execute(string script, params object[] arguments) { ... }

/// <summary>
/// Runs the <see cref="Execute"/> method asynchronously. 
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// An awaitable task, with the text output of the script as 
/// <see cref="Task{TResult}.Result"/>.
/// </returns>
/// <seealso cref="Execute"/>
public Task<string> ExecuteAsync(string script, params object[] arguments) { ... }

/// <summary>
/// Executes a Python script and returns the resulting image 
/// (mostly a chart that was produced
/// by a Python package like e.g. <see href="https://matplotlib.org/">matplotlib</see> or
/// <see href="https://seaborn.pydata.org/">seaborn</see>).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="script">Full path to the script to execute.</param>
/// <param name="arguments">Arguments that were passed to the script.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="Bitmap"/> that the script creates.</returns>
/// <exception cref="PythonRunnerException">
/// Thrown if error text was outputted by the script (this normally happens
/// if an exception was raised by the script). <br/>
/// -- or -- <br/>
/// An unexpected error happened during script execution. In this case, the
/// <see cref="Exception.InnerException"/> property contains the original
/// <see cref="Exception"/>.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
/// Argument <paramref name="script"/> is null.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="FileNotFoundException">
/// Argument <paramref name="script"/> is an invalid path.
/// </exception>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// In a 'normal' case, a Python script that creates a chart would show this chart
/// with the help of Python's own backend, like this.
/// <example>
/// import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
/// ...
/// plt.show()
/// </example>
/// For the script to be used within the context of this <see cref="PythonRunner"/>,
/// it should instead convert the image to a base64-encoded string and print this string
/// to the console. The following code snippet shows a Python method (<c>print_figure</c>)
/// that does this:
/// <example>
/// import io, sys, base64
/// 
/// def print_figure(fig):
///     buf = io.BytesIO()
///     fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
///     print(base64.b64encode(buf.getbuffer()))
///
/// import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
/// ...
/// print_figure(plt.gcf()) # the gcf() method retrieves the current figure
/// </example>
/// </para><para>
/// Output to the error stream can also come from warnings, that are frequently
/// outputted by various python package components. These warnings would result
/// in an exception, therefore they must be switched off within the script by
/// including the following statement: <c>warnings.simplefilter("ignore")</c>.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
public Bitmap GetImage(string script, params object[] arguments) { ... }

/// <summary>
/// Runs the <see cref="GetImage"/> method asynchronously. 
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// An awaitable task, with the <see cref="Bitmap"/> that the script
/// creates as <see cref="Task{TResult}.Result"/>.
/// </returns>
/// <seealso cref="GetImage"/>
public Task<Bitmap> GetImageAsync(string script, params object[] arguments) { ... }
  }
```

As already mentioned, the sample app uses a SQLite database as its datastore (which is also accessed by the Python side - see below). To this end, Entity Framework is used, together with the recipe found in this Codeproject article. The stock data are then put into a ListCollectionView, which supports filtering and sorting:

```
private void LoadStocks()
{
var ctx = new SQLiteDatabaseContext(_mainVm.DbPath);

var itemList = ctx.Stocks.ToList().Select(s => new StockItem(s)).ToList();
_stocks = new ObservableCollection<StockItem>(itemList);
_collectionView = new ListCollectionView(_stocks);

// Initially sort the list by stock names
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_collectionView);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

Getting Textual Output
Here, PythonRunner is calling a script that produces textual output. The KMeansClusteringScript property points to the script to execute:

```
private async Task<string> RunKMeans()
{
TreeViewText = Processing;
Items.Clear();

try
{
    string output = await _mainVm.PythonRunner.ExecuteAsync(
        KMeansClusteringScript,
        _mainVm.DbPath,
        _mainVm.TickerList,
        _mainVm.NumClusters,
        _mainVm.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        _mainVm.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    return output;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    TreeViewText = e.ToString();
    return string.Empty;
}
}
```

And here is some sample output produced by the script:

```
  0 AYR 0,0,255
  0 PCCWY 0,100,0
  0 HSNGY 128,128,128
  0 CRHKY 165,42,42
  0 IBN 128,128,0
  1 SRNN 199,21,133
   ...
  4 PNBK 139,0,0
  5 BOTJ 255,165,0
  5 SPPJY 47,79,79
```

The first column is the cluster number of the k-Means analysis, the second column is the ticker symbol of the respective stock, and the third column indicates the RGB values of the color that was used to draw this stock's line in the chart.

```
Getting an Image
```

This is the method that uses viewmodel's PythonRunner instance for asynchronously calling the required Python script (the path of which is stored in the DrawSummaryLineChartScript property) together with the required script arguments. The result is then processed into a 'WPF-friendly' form, as soon as it becomes available:

```
internal async Task<bool> DrawChart()
{
SummaryChartText = Processing;
SummaryChart = null;

try
{
        SummaryChart = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
        bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
        IntPtr.Zero,
        Int32Rect.Empty,
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    return true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    SummaryChartText = e.ToString();
    return false;
}
 }
```

but this method not work correctly ? what I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls the python script to draw the chart of the selected stocks.

```
internal async Task<bool> DrawChart()
 {
   SummaryChartText = Processing;
    SummaryChart = null;

try
{
    var bitmap = await _mainVm.PythonRunner.GetImageAsync(
        DrawSummaryLineChartScript,
        _mainVm.DbPath,
        _mainVm.TickerList,
        _mainVm.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        _mainVm.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    SummaryChart = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
        bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
        IntPtr.Zero,
        Int32Rect.Empty,
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    return true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    SummaryChartText = e.ToString();
    return false;
}
}
```